# Please explain this SerializationException to me

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

The simple class below inherits from HashSet and thus has to implement the ISerialization members (in a non standard way). I get the following Exception when I try to serialize then deserialize an instance of Group:

> Test method
>   UtilitiesTests.GroupTest.SerializeTest
>   threw exception: 
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Het doel van een aanroep heeft een
>   uitzondering veroorzaakt. ---> 
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:
>   Lid nameprop is niet gevonden..

Unfortunately this is in dutch. It means that the member "nameprop"  could not be found!
What is wrong??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Grouping
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Group<T> : HashSet<T>
    {
        public Group(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        protected Group(){}

        protected Group(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context):base(info,context)
        {
            Name = info.GetString("nameprop");
        }

        protected new void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
        {
            base.GetObjectData(info,context);
            info.AddValue("nameprop", Name);
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to surpress error, checkout this note from http://lifeelement.com. SerializationException Member was not found<br />
http://lifeelement.com/news/serializationexception-member-was-not-found/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GetObjectData` method is never called during serialization, because you don't override the parent method - you shadow it. You should use `override` rather than `new` there.

Comment: Thanks! That was it...
Could you point me to the the english error message so as to make this question easier to find by other simpletons like me?

Comment: I don't know as I didn't actually run the code, only looked at it :)